# Webscraping to extract coordinates from embedded Google Map link

Tags: python, google-maps, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, coordinates

```
import requests
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd
import bs4

url = 'https://www.namus.gov/MissingPersons/Case#/53061'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html')
#print(soup.prettify())

findall = soup.find_all("a")

for link in findall:
    pprint(link.get("ng-href"))
```

When I run the code I set a tuple instead of the link. I've tried referencing the href, src, ng-href and non work. I can only pull the subSection when I really need the link to google maps as a string.

```
#I get this: u'{{subSection.mapLink()}}'
#when I really need this: #"http://www.google.com/maps/place/35.9467011,-84.03260329999999"
```

The actual string I'm attempting to scrape looks as such:

```
<a ng-if="subSection.mapLink()" class="icon-text-link" ng-href="http://www.google.com/maps/place/35.9467011,-84.03260329999999" target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/maps/place/35.9467011,-84.03260329999999">
                <i class="icon-location-pin"></i><span>Map</span>
            </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is an angular website, there are a lot of information which are loaded dynamically using Javascript, you can check the network tab to know from where those data are retrieved. In this case, this is a JSON API with the following template :

```
https://www.namus.gov/api/CaseSets/NamUs/MissingPersons/Cases/{CASE_ID}
```

It gives you all information which is embedded in the page, the map url can be built dynamically, for instance :

```
import requests

id = '53061'
resp = requests.get('https://www.namus.gov/api/CaseSets/NamUs/MissingPersons/Cases/{}'.format(id))
body = resp.json()

loc = body['sighting']['publicGeolocation']
coord = loc['coordinates']
print("address         : " + loc['formattedAddress'])
print("google map link : " + "http://www.google.com/maps/place/{},{}".format(coord['lat'],coord['lon']))
```